# A framework for financial modelling

Tags: framework, finance

I aim to improve my passive investment decisions. I'd like to have a system with 2 main components: (a) monitoring economic/financial data on the Internet and (b) econometric analysis of the data.

I can do (a) and (b) individually but it is not sustainable to do so. Moreover, I wouldn't want to implement low-level time-series modeling myself. I'd like a framework that would allow me to simply add financial data and put models on to it, preferably an object-oriented framework with strong meta enforcements (akin to strongly-typed languages). What I mean by this is that I would prefer a framework that is more or less aware of financial constructs such as currency, time and returns.

I do not have a programming language requirement, although I think support for econometric models might be a limiting factor here. I think Python might be the most suitable language with a good functionality in both scripting and financial analysis. I am personally more experienced in PhP, Java and R.

I am mainly looking for free or fremium models, since it is a personal project. But I might consider paying small fees like app fees if it will save me some time. No license considerations as long as the software allows me to work on it and use it individually.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you desire strongly typed or static typed languages. Is Python okay?

Comment: @EricShain, It is OK. In fact, it might be the most suitable language with a good functionality in both scripting and financial analysis.